image don't show up in react application
i have a component and image in the same foalder
import classes from './Header.module.css'

import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.header}>
            <div className={classes.logo}>
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;


But in browser i see, that browser doesn't see thi image, but in WebStorm if i cover img, i see it.


You cant use your logo.png in same folder. Instead you should move your image to your public folder of your project.

Move your icon to the public folder of your project. Then try to load your icon.png.

You can also make folders for your icons or images in public folder.
